# FAILED status in Elastix CDR reports

Tags: linux, voip

What are all the possible reasons on Elastix to log an inbound call with 'FAILED' status?
I'm generating a CDR report and there's a bunch of calls (around 30%) with this status. Additional values of important fields:

- duration is always 0 seconds
- Destiny is always an extension (that's the reason for my doubts supposing my server was unable to reach the SIP client, the call is assigned )

There are other statuses like BUSY and NO ANSWER so this two should not be reasons for the call to fail.
Could it be that the caller hangs up? any other reason?
(sorry for my "english")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for the failed status is "subscriber absent", searching in the logs:

> Unable to create channel of type 'SIP' (cause 20 - Subscriber
>   absent)

So, as I supposed, the server was unable to reach the SIP Client most of the time.